# Any way to check a PS3 controller's battery on Ubuntu?

Tags: power-management, games, battery, sony, ps3

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I use a Sony Dualshock 3 Controller to play a few games on Steam. As I tend to use the controller wirelessly for long periods of time, it's not uncommon to have the controller suddenly dying on me when the battery gets really discharged.

I searched around the internet but couldn't find a way to check how much battery left I had on the controller. Is there any native way to check a PS3 controller's battery, or some script I could use?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the [Dual Shock 4 battery percentage](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1283/dual-shock-4-battery-percentage/) extension for Gnome. Although the name mentions DS4, it also supports DS3 (which I am using) and should soon support DS5 with recent kernels.

Behind the scenes, this extension simply relies on the power supply subsystem, and more specifically the file located at:

```
/sys/class/power_supply/<controller_identifier>/capacity
```